# How to disable the Image using class name.. using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$(".ui-datepicker-trigger").attr('disabled',true);
```

I am trying to disable the Image button something like this.. but its not working

but if I do its working

`$(".ui-datepicker-trigger").hide();` hide is wokring but disabled is not working?

can any body tell me?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Datepicker has a built-in [`disable` method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-disable) for this you can use, which also disables the text input, like this:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker("disable");
```

[You can view a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZL2A/), you need to use this method if possible, because the datepicker actually tracks what's disabled internally, [you can see the source code here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js#L373).

The alternative would be to manually [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the click from that image, like this:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-trigger").css({opacity:'0.5',cursor:'default'}).unbind('click');
```

​
[You can see a demo of that here](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZL2A/1/), the [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) part is just to give it some "disabled" styling :)

Answer (score 1):

I added the img and bound a click handler using jQuery. So, when I disable everything else, I also unbind that click handler so the image button doesn't work anymore.  Anyhow, here is an updated working example.  I tested this in IE and FF.  Let me know how it goes.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
       $("button").click(function(event){
         alert("you clicked the link, everything should be disabled now.");
         $(".ui-datepicker-trigger").attr('disabled',true);
         $("img.ui-datepicker-trigger").unbind('click');
       });

        // add a click handler for the img element
        $("img.ui-datepicker-trigger").bind('click', function() {alert('clicked the img');});

     });

   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <button class="ui-datepicker-trigger">Disable Everything</button>
   <br/>
   <input type="text" id="txt1" class="ui-datepicker-trigger" value="textbox 1"></input>

   <img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="calendar.jpg" alt="..." title="..." style="display: inline;">
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: <img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" src="/Content/images/calender.gif" alt="..." title="..." style="display: inline;"> Thanks

Answer (score -1):

if someone is trying to HIDE the button next to the date picker, use the option: 'showOn':'focus' in the object you send to the constructor when calling the Datepicker object. Watch here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showOn